# 401 Cert Master-Detail Permissions Question

Tags: dev401

I am preparing for Cert 401 and here is one question I am confused with:

> An organization has two custom objects to track job positions and
>   salaries for those positions. Everyone in the organization should be
>   able to view the positions however, only select users can view the
>   salary records. What steps should a developer take to ensure the
>   requirement is fulfilled?
>
> - A - Create a lookup relationship between positions and salaries;    define public access on position and private access on salary
> - B - Create a master-detail relationship between positions and salaries;    define public access on position and private access on
>     salary.
> - C - Create a master-detail relationship between positions and salaries;    define private access on position and create sharing
>     rules on salary.
> - D - Create a lookup relationship between positions and salaries;    define public access on position and public access on salary; create
>     sharing rules on salary to restrict visibility.

I searched through google about this question and all the websites suggest the correct answer is A. But why not B? As the question clearly suggests that salary is created for positions and salary itself doesn't make sense without a position. Is it due to some security reason?

Answer (score 10):

With Master-Detail relationships, permissions can't be set for the child object - they are defined by the sharing rules on the Parent - so if you can see Positions, you can see Salaries as well...

Comment: Ah... almost forgot that. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

In the lookup relationship both object are independent for sharing rules and having owner field on object.
master details relationship only parent object having **owner field** and child don't have owner field which means child records are dependent on parent record.